# How to get device id in react js based web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a reactjs based application. I want to limit the login from multiple devices at one time to an account. So I need to have an ID that is unique and fixed on device.

I also want the user to stay logged in on one device, so I can not use IP address.

Also, I've already limited access from several browsers.

Thanks a lot. Also, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

This check can't be implemented on client side of the application.

On the server end, you can get IP address from requested payload. You can store the IP address against the session in In-memory databases like redis or memcache. Now, create an intermediate check at login controller where you can block the user if he/she has logged in more than certain number of IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm also keep user login in one device. so I can't use IP address.

Comment: Since HTTP is stateless, if you say user is logged in one device then there will be some session on the server. Either, sticky or non-sticky session such as redis session. Now, redis is nothing but a key value store. Where you can store an object, which can also contain number of IP address used by the user.